# Django objects queryset filter by matching datetime

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have a model with a field name 'timestamp' that is a datetime field, and when I print them in python manage.py shell I get:

```
>>> a.timestamp
datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 15, 18, 45, tzinfo=<UTC>)
```

Now.... I am running django celery task every 30 seconds that suppose to retrieve all the matching objects in the last 30 seconds.

how can I do it (thing = MyModelName.objects.filter(.. something ..)

I hope that I manage to explain my self.

Thank you all in advanced.

Update:
When I am typing in my server (python shell)

datetime.datetime.now()
I am getting

datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 15, 20, 34, 4, 366166)

Comment: What exactly are you having trouble with?

Comment: Just updated my question.
The problem that I am having is that I am not getting the matching objects.
maybe it has something to do with timezone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
MyModelName.objects.filter(timestamp__gte=(datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(seconds=30)))
```

Comment: With your code I am getting all the object every 30 seconds, which is not good. :(

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: That shouldn't be the case - but you could try `django.utils.timezone.now()` instead of `datetime.datetime.now()`.  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/utils/#django.utils.timezone.now

Answer (score 1):

```
import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

time = datetime.datetime.now()
delta = timedelta(seconds=30)
newtime = time + delta #after adding 30 sec with current time

so you can loop through the (newtime - time) time interval then  you can
get the expected result.
```